# phonegap icon/splash screen path for cli build

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-cli

While creating my app I issues the command:

> phonegap create appdir com.site.myapp myapp

so now the appdir folder has the following.

```
-.cordova
-hooks
-platforms
-plugins
-www
-config.xml-----(config.xml is generated at top level)
```

In my www folder i have one index.html and one image that I want to use as my icon

```
www
-index.html
-icon.png
```

1)so which do I give the path for the  tag in the config.xml file?

2)where do I put the config file do i need to move the config file inside the www folder like in phonegapbuild

I have tried various path combinations but none is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Android, The application icon is located here: *res/drawable/*

So replace **icon.png** there.

Same thing for splash screen, replacing res/drawable/**screen.png**.